# How to make the first character of first word lowercase in PHP?

Tags: php, lowercase

How to convert this:

```
"Elephant, Africa, landscape"
```

into this:

```
"elephant, Africa, landscape"
```

I tried using [strlower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php) and [lcfirst](http://php.net/manual/en/function.lcfirst.php) php functions, but that is not what I wish. I wish just fist character of just first word to be lowercase, not all sentence lowercase or all words to be with first character lowercase.

Is there something to get first character of first word only lowercase?

**UPDATE:**

I wish to show post title as keywords, and I use this:

```
$title = get_the_title( $post->post_parent ); // Get post title
$parts = explode( ' ', $title ); // Delimetar for words in post title " "
$str = '';
foreach ($parts as $word) {
    $str.= lcfirst(post_title_as_keywords($word)); // Lowercase first character
}
$str = substr($str, 0,-2);
echo $str;
```

And this is what I get:

"elephant, africa, landscape"

How to prevent lowercase effect on all words?

Comment: How is `lcfirst()` not doing what you wish? Is it because of the lack of unicode? [If it is, here's a gist for `mb_lcfirst()`](https://github.com/abahdanovich/Slim-web-framework/blob/master/lib/Smarty/plugins/modifier.mb_lcfirst.php).

Comment: lcfirst does exactly what you want. Please read the documentation and try it out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.lcfirst.php

Comment: What is lcfirst doing for you that you do not like?

Comment: With lcfirst I get "elephant, africa, landscape".

Comment: This is what I get when I run lcfirst() on the console:

php > echo lcfirst("Elephant, Africa, landscape");
elephant, Africa, landscape

Check your code/input string, the function works fine.

Comment: I updated my question, please read again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `lcfirst()` once per word (inside the `for` loop). Try applying `lcfirst()` to str *after* the loop, instead of inside it:

```
$str = lcfirst(substr($str, 0,-2));
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP Version: > 5.3.0:

*The lcfirst() function converts the first character of a string to lowercase.*

```
echo lcfirst("Elephant, Africa, landscape");

//output elephant, Africa, landscape
```

[have a look at w3c schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_lcfirst.asp)

For PHP < 5.3 use

```
$your_string = "Elephant, Africa, landscape";
$your_string[0] = strtolower($str[0]);

//output elephant, Africa, landscape
```

**UPDATE:**

Use the function not inside your foreach-loop will fix your issue.